# Graphql Wrapper for Rest APIs with Django

Tags: django, rest, graphql, wrapper, graphene-django

Trying to implement wrapper for existing REST APIS using Django graphQL.

Found similar one in JS but not in Django.
https://graphql.org/blog/rest-api-graphql-wrapper/
Could anyone please suggest if there is a GraphQL Django wrapper for REST calls. Haven't found in documentation either

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a rest API using DRF? I'd suggest you look at [graphene-django-cud](https://github.com/tOgg1/graphene-django-cud) to help you with mutations. Graphene-django is required for this, and will help with your queries. Unfortunately it's not a wrapper that will convert all your DRF code into graphql, however you should be able to basically copy paste a lot of the content in your serializers/views.

Comment: Thanks for your response . I am looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541204/graphene-relation-using-restfull-api-as-data-source.     Now fighting for dataloaders and authentication for graphene.Object types which basically don't have a model.